# How to make JS framework custom functions work for dynamically added elements?

Tags: javascript, mdc-components

I'm using @material/select. Options are added from JS script after AJAX call: (Simplified code)

```
for (let key in data.directories){
    $("#selector-options").append('<li data-value="'+data.directories[key]+'" role="option">\n' +
        '                             <span>'+data.directories[key]+'</span>\n' +
        '                          </li>')
}
```

And the Material listener code looks like this (Fires when user chose an option):

```
import {MDCSelect} from '@material/select';
const select = new MDCSelect(document.querySelector('.mdc-select'));
select.listen('MDCSelect:change', () => {
    alert(`Selected option at index ${select.selectedIndex} with value "${select.value}"`);
});
```

What I have to do is make an AJAX request when user choose an option, but MDCSelect code runs before AJAX request (to get `data`), and generated options are not handled correctly.
How can I make MDCSelect code run after AJAX request? Also I can dynamically add options using PHP, but can I make it using JS only?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by including a PHP script into `admin.blade.php` (Laravel):

```
@for ($i=0;$i<count($directories);$i++)
   <li class="mdc-list-item" aria-selected="false" data-value="{{$directories[$i]}}" role="option">
     <span class="mdc-list-item__ripple"></span>
     <span class="mdc-list-item__text">{{$directories[$i]}}</span>
   </li>
@endfor
```

Now everything works fine, but I feel sad